# Is there any way to change Sitecore Rocks Sub layout template structure (VS 2013)?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-rocks

When I create new item -> sub layout it will create web user control. I need change the template structure of web user control's code behind file (using should come outside of namespace) when it creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default templates for the Sitecore Items is in the following folder:

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions\<install-id>\ItemTemplates\Sitecore`

Extract Sublayouts.zip file from Sublayouts folder, move the `using` statement to outside the namespace in `Sublayout.ascx.cs` and re-pack the zip file. Restart Visual Studio and the changes should take effect.